# Novice question about setting system clock in microcontrollers

Tags: microcontroller, clock

This is a novice question. I see that for every embdded project system clock is set by using PLL multipliers.

But what determines the system clock value? Why not always max system clock is used? Can you give an example?

Comment: Clock frequency === power usage. Thus to have your batteries last as long as possible, you would try to turn the clock frequency down every time you don't need to do a lot of calculations.

Comment: But there are zillons of possible clock freq settings. How does one know what freq is adequate for a task? Example would help.

Comment: Simplest is that once you have done what you need to do, you set the clock freq. very low waiting for an event to happen.

Comment: Im talking about the system clock freq

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of embedded microcontrollers that have no PLL, so your assumption is wrong that everything has a PLL.

The maximum system clock is not always needed, or can't be used.

There might be restrictions on power usage where for example batteries would drain too fast.

There might be restrictions on available supply voltage, so with the available supply voltage, the system will work but maximum frequency cannot be reached.

Sometimes, a certain peripheral might need a specific clock to communicate at right speed with other devices with minimal deviation from the nominal speed. For example an AVR MCU running at 2 MHz clock can't communicate at 115200 baud rate, but it can when using a slightly lower 1.8432 MHz clock.

Comment: Are you talking about the system clock freq?

Comment: Yes, many simpler systems have no PLL, they simply use the externally or internally supplied clock as-is and they use it for everything. Also PLLs have their limitations with the multipliers and dividers so with certain reference clock you can only synthesize certain frequencies. If you have a specific system you are talking about, perhaps you would like to mention which system you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

The system clock frequency of the microcontroller is determined by the clock oscillator used (or clock frequency driven to the microcontroller's CLKIN pin) *and possibly also by a PLL* which modifies the clock frequency (typically a multipler).

- As Justme mentions, not all microcontrollers have a PLL. Sometimes it's just the input clock.
- As Oldfart hints in his comments, the PLL can be used to dynamically adjust the system clock frequency: faster clock when you need it, slower clock when you don't.

I'm not certain, but I believe your real question is "how do I determine what clock frequency to use? Why not just always choose the fastest possible?" When choosing a clock frequency, there are typically a large number of "correct" answers and you just need to find one that works well for your particular application. Things to consider:

- As you imply in your question, a faster clock is good because it enables the microcontroller to perform its computations faster.
- But, as Oldfart mentions in his comment, the power consumption of a microcontroller scales directly with frequency. Exact formula is \$P=CV^2f\$ ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_power_dissipation)). So for power-sensitive applications (for example anything battery-powered) you'd like to make the system clock frequency as low as possible.

We combine the above two points to conclude that, for many applications, we'd like the microcontroller's system clock frequency to be *the slowest frequency that still gets the job done*. Of course "gets the job done" is a matter of opinion, especially when you need to worry about things like future expansion.

A hypothetical example:

- Imagine you're using a microcontroller to decode an incoming digital radio signal.
- The digital radio signal is just a sequence of symbols arriving at a rate of 1000 symbols per second.
- The microcontroller is running off a 25MHz clock, which we can multiply up to a 50MHz clock or a 100MHz clock.
- When it is running at 25MHz, the microcontroller takes 1.2ms to decode an incoming symbol. We can assume that processing speed will scale directly with clock speed.

In this case, what would be the correct clock frequency to choose?

- We get a new input symbol every 1.0ms, so we cannot use a clock frequency of 25MHz since the processor needs more time than that to process a symbol at this clock speed.
- With a clock frequency of 50MHz, the processor should need 0.6ms to process a symbol, so it's fast enough to handle the task.
- With a clock frequency of 100MHz, the processor should need only 0.3ms to process a symbol, so it's more than fast enough.

In this hypothetical example, the most people would choose 50MHz. If you go to 100MHz you consume 2x the power of the 50MHz design, and there is no real benefit; the 50MHz design already spends 0.4ms out of every 1.0ms just sitting around waiting for the next symbol to arrive; the 100MHz design would simply spend 0.7ms out of every 1.0 ms waiting.

*But*, some designers might choose the 100MHz design anyway. If the extra power consumption is not a concern, then the 100MHz design allows the option to add a lot more computation to the code and the end result will still run fast enough for the application. *(And some designers might choose the 25MHz design, saying "I really need to conserve power, and I can just optimize my code to bring that processing time down from 1.2ms to 1.0ms!)*